# Testing in the Hadoop platform

Tags: testing, hadoop, hive, apache-pig

When doing web development we can test our apps with tools and methodologies such as unit testing (jUnit, rspec, ...), TDD, BDD, cucumber, end-to-end/regression/integration tests, H2 (as in process database), ...

But in the Hadoop and Big Data world,

**How do you test a hadoop/hive/pig code?** By that I mean creating an automation for the situation that given I have a sample input, when I trigger some hive or pig script, then I verify the output is as expected.

With more details, **Is there a way to get a quick feedback of these automated tests?** More specifically, how to run in-memory HDFS? In Java with SQL databases, we use H2 to get this quick feedback.

Or more broadly, **what are the testing strategies that people use in the Hadoop platform?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm working as part of a team to support a big data and analytics platform, and we also have this kind of issue.

We've been searching for a while and we found two pretty promising tools:
https://github.com/klarna/HiveRunner
https://github.com/bobfreitas/HadoopMiniCluster

Hope it helps you =)